# A simple RequiredField validator really this complex?

Tags: validation, silverlight-4.0, mvvm, mvvm-light, wcf-ria-services

Using the INotifyDataErrorInfo I have validation methods in my setters of my properties, this works fine if I change the field value and then leave the control (change focus) the setter gets fired and validation occurs and the UI is notified, but using that interface, if the user just presses submit how can I do something similar to RequiredField like in asp.net, I can't seem to find a clear cut example on any forum or blog :(

I'm using Silverlight 4 WCF RIA and the mvvm-light toolkit, thats it. I hope im not over complexing this, because it seems like it should be so simple but can't seem to figure out a solution.

Thank you for all your help, suggestions and pointers!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a simple solution... Please let me know if anyone has a more efficient way of doing this :)

```
        private void Validate()
        {
            ValidationContext validationContext = new ValidationContext(this, null, null);
            ICollection vr = new List();
            Validator.TryValidateObject(this, validationContext, vr, true);
            if (vr.Count >= 1)
            {
                foreach (var item in vr)
                {
                    ManageErrors(((string[])item.MemberNames)[0], new List() { item.ErrorMessage }, true);
                }
            }
        }
```

The Manage Errors method is the simple implementation of the INotifyDataErrorInfo that Jesse Liberty did [here](http://jesseliberty.com/2010/08/02/async-data-validation/)

any ways now when my submit method gets called (using mvvm-light) in my viewModel i call this and bam all properties validated using simple dataAnnotations
ie

```
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Is Required", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        public string SelectedStatus
        {
            get { return _selectedStatus; }
            set
            {
                _selectedStatus = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedStatus");
            }
        }
```

Not the most elegant way of doing it but... by god I could not find anyone validating on a submit!?!?